# Laravel Filament v3 automatic logout if SESSION_DRIVER=database

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream, laravel-filament, filamentphp

### Problem:

I'm currently trying to implement [filament v3](https://filamentphp.com/docs) into my current [laravel v10](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x) project also using [livewire v3](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart).

After installing filament v3 as described in their installation guide I am able to see the filament login screen where I can log in under certain conditions:

- The first login works with my already before existing user credentials just fine.
- If I then get redirected to the default filament dashboard and want to click on "Dashboard" again I automatically get logged out and redirected to the filament login screen (This should not redirect me at all).
- Also if I now want to log in again, the browser shows me a message saying "This page has expired. Would you like to refresh the page?"
- If I now click refresh I'm trapped in a loop... I am now at the login screen again (not logged in).
- The only thing to exit this loop is to manually refresh the page once more and try to log in again.
- Then I'm back at the dashboard, getting logged out automatically
  again if clicking on "Dashboard" again as before.
- The only way to stay logged in can be achieved if I check the checkbox "Remember me" before the first login.
- Now I can stay logged in to the filament dashboard, but if I now click on "Log out" I get a "Laravel POST Error".
- Also if I log in to my current app before and then try to access the filament dashboard I also immediately get logged out and redirected to the filament login screen...

### What I tried so far:

I have already searched everywhere I could and found just a few people with the same or a similar problem:

- **This (https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/8574) is an discussion I found on the filament repo on github which represents my problem the best. If I change my `SESSION_DRIVER` to `SESSION_DRIVER=file` instead of `SESSION_DRIVER=database` everything works as expected but I can't find the solution WHY?!**
- I also ruled out I is a bug on a clean laravel v10 / filament v3 install. Here also everything works fine (Also with `SESSION_DRIVER=database`).

### Things I also tested / resources I checked:

- https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/issues/2328
- https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/4959

### System info:

- MacOS 14.3.1
- PHPStorm 2023.2
- Chrome 121.0.6167.160
- Laravel 10.44.0
- Livewire 3.4.4
- Filament 3.2.34
- PHP 8.1

## EDIT:

I now found a solution to bypass the problem:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Filament;

use Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DisableBladeIconComponents;
use Filament\Http\Middleware\DispatchServingFilamentEvent;
use Filament\Pages;
use Filament\Panel;
use Filament\PanelProvider;
use Filament\Support\Colors\Color;
use Filament\Widgets;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;

class AdminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        return $panel
            ->default()
            ->id('admin')
            ->path('admin')
            ->login()
            ->colors([
                'primary' => Color::Rose,
            ])
            ->discoverResources(in: app_path('Filament/Resources'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Resources')
            ->discoverPages(in: app_path('Filament/Pages'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Pages')
            ->pages([
                Pages\Dashboard::class,
            ])
            ->discoverWidgets(in: app_path('Filament/Widgets'), for: 'App\\Filament\\Widgets')
            ->widgets([
                Widgets\AccountWidget::class,
                Widgets\FilamentInfoWidget::class,
            ])
            ->middleware([
                EncryptCookies::class,
                AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                // StartSession::class, -> just commented out this line
                AuthenticateSession::class,
                ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                SubstituteBindings::class,
                DisableBladeIconComponents::class,
                DispatchServingFilamentEvent::class,
            ])
            ->authMiddleware([
                Authenticate::class,
            ]);
    }
}
```

**Now I'm not completely sure if this is okay to do.**

What I've encountered before:
Every time I go to the filament dashboard or am redirected to the filament login screen a new session entry get's generated in the database where the old one get's abandoned (not deleted as normally when logging out).

After commenting out `StartSession::class` in my `AdminPanelProvider.php` file this is no longer the case.
Now every time I log in (or log out) the session get's updated (or deleted and a new one get's created).

Is this safe to implement like this?
Also why is it working just fine if `SESSION_DRIVER=file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on to this question... I finally found a solution for my project.
Although it's very unlikely anyone else is experiencing the exact same issue I will still post my findings:)

For me the reason for the bug could be found in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

**The following changes fixed it for me:**

[image: changes in app/Http/Kernel.php]

A bit on the background:

The project was started with [Laravel v7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x) and grew since then... Maybe those days the `Kernel.php` file looked different to the todays version or I just modified it some time ago.